# how to display n records per column in crystal report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, format

I am designing a Crystal report in VS 2010 in that report the result set may Display 20 Rows per column like

```
         1.Row1
         2.Row2
         3.Row3
         4.Row4
         5.Row5
         6.Row6
         7.Row7
         8.Row8
         9.Row9
         10.Row10
         11.Row11
         12.Row12
         13.Row13
         14.Row14
         15.Row15
         16.Row16
         17.Row17
         18.Row18
         19.Row19
         20.Row20
```

but I want to display as 10 records Per column like,

```
         1.Row1   11.Row11
         2.Row2   12.Row12
         3.Row3   13.Row13
         4.Row4   14.Row14
         5.Row5   15.Row15
         6.Row6   16.Row16
         7.Row7   17.Row17
         8.Row8   18.Row18
         9.Row9   19.Row19
         10.Row10 20.Row20
```

Can anybody help How to achieve this kind of design in my report

**Edit**

I had tried the `Format with Multiple Column` option in the details section of the report.But the result set is Displaying in one line like

```
         1.Row1
         2.Row2
         3.Row3
         4.Row4
         5.Row5
         6.Row6
         7.Row7
         8.Row8
         9.Row9
         10.Row10
         11.Row11
         12.Row12
         13.Row13
         14.Row14
         15.Row15
         16.Row16
         17.Row17
         18.Row18
         19.Row19
         20.Row20
```

not separately. Kindly any one tell what still needed other than

```
Format with Multiple columns
```

Note:Also I cant Specify height in the `Layout` Tab of details view as it is disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
In "Section Expert" go to "Details" and check the  "Format with Multiple 
Columns" box. A new tab by name "Layout" will be added on the top. Select that 
tab. There  you specify the Width , Horizontal & Vertical Gap and than select 
"Across then Down" or "Down then Across" as per your need.

Hope that helps,

Chris