# How to design a Format with Multiple Column Report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, format

I am designing a report With the `Format With Multiple Columns` option in the crystal report to display 10 records per column.But, my result set is Showing like,

```
     1.Row1
     2.Row2
     3.Row3
     4.Row4
     5.Row5
     6.Row6
     7.Row7
     8.Row8
     9.Row9
     10.Row10
     11.Row11
     12.Row12
     13.Row13
     14.Row14
     15.Row15
     16.Row16
     17.Row17
     18.Row18
     19.Row19
     20.Row20
```

instead of

```
     1.Row1   11.Row11
     2.Row2   12.Row12
     3.Row3   13.Row13
     4.Row4   14.Row14
     5.Row5   15.Row15
     6.Row6   16.Row16
     7.Row7   17.Row17
     8.Row8   18.Row18
     9.Row9   19.Row19
     10.Row10 20.Row20
```

what else I had to do to split the rows and display.

Note: I had already asked this kind of Question and got the answer to use `Format With Multiple Column` in this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19560941/how-to-display-n-records-per-column-in-crystal-report).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to set multiple columns you have first to do to Report -> Section Expert

Then in the details section you have to check Format with multiple columns

[image]

After that you should select the layout tab and set width of your column and the gab between them.

[image]

Comment: @ Raphel Do I have to choose the `Printing Direction` in order to display in `Across`?

Comment: what do you have on the rest of the report? Unfortunately it seems that there is no way to set a column split number, you have to way to do that, first you can set the vertical page size (File->Page Setup), or better You could arrange the data inside a subreport, constrained to the height you want, and configured for multiple columns.

Comment: I don't see where this answer is any different than the one you got in your other post.

Comment: @Raphael I had added the `Report Footer` portion to `Page Footer` portion it had worked.

Comment: @ campagnolo_1 Sorry My mistake Instead of Giving him +1 for his effort I had marked it as answer now I had Changed it.